# gcloud authentication without opening browser?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

To get my ADC(application default configuration) for gcloud, I must run:

```
$ gcloud auth application-default login
```

However, it spits out a link that it tells my browser to visit(which I can't due to permission restrictions at work).

I read through the man pages, and I saw there was a flag called `--no-launch-browser`. I tried it, and it still told me to go to a link in my browser, followed by a verification code. That's a bit of a misnomer, isn't it?

So what can I do so I can actually access my gcloud ADC?

Comment: Have you tried service account?

Comment: Exactly, 'gcloud auth activate-service-account' will authorize access to Google Cloud with a service account. You need the SA credentials accessible to your environment - and that is less secure that user authentication unless you diligently rotate the keys.

Answer (score 8):

The browser is launched only if the `DISPLAY` variable is set; if not, the `gcloud auth application-default login` command prints a URL to standard output to be copied. The printing of the URL to the standard output can be secured in any case, if the `--no-launch-browser` flag is set.

You are supposed to use the URL in a browser of your choice, to get the verification code to be provided to the "Enter verification code:" prompt.

Comment: Thanks George. I have accepted your answer but I realized that there is just no way to sign on without having to open a browser. The --no-launch-browser flag just allows you to paste it into ANY browser(aka it doesn't even need to be the same IP on your computer).

Comment: Doesn't seem to me that this should be accepted as it is not a solution to your problem.

Comment: Great blog post on this issue and solution: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ubuntu-on-windows/9NBLGGH4MSV6?hl=en-us&gl=us

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is a service account. Using curl or wget might also be an option depending on what prevents you from using a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

1. Download service JSON file.
2. Execute command:

   gcloud auth login --cred-file=YOUR_CONFIGURATION_OR_KEY_FILE
3. It will authenticate without any browser.